# Style of defining output elements in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Is there any clear preference between these two options that both create the same result (given that ns0 is defined as http://MyNamespace.

```
<ns0:N9> 
</ns0:N9>
```

vs.

```
<xsl:element name="N9" namespace="http://MyNamespace">
</xsl:element>
```

A co-worker was rather adamant that the second example should not be used, but I was thinking it was actually more elegant and XSLT-ish.  He said that we should be able to change the namespace at the top, without having to do a replace-all on the entire document (either is simple with a good editor).

The first is obviously smaller and takes less characters.

Comment: Yes, the preference is to use `xsl:element` when the name needs to be determined dynamically at runtime. Otherwise use a literal result element.

Comment: If XSLT-ish = verbose, then yes the second option is more XSLT-ish. I agree with your co-worker. I only ever use xsl:element when I need to dynamically generate the name.

Comment: Note you can actually do `<xsl:element name="ns0:N9">` in this case, so you could still "change the namespace at the top". But it doesn't give any benefit over doing`<ns0:N9>` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see any possible reason to prefer `xsl:element` over a literal result element, except when

(a) the name is computed dynamically, or

(b) you want finer control over the namespaces, rather than the default handling that a literal result element gives you, or

(c) you're paid by the quantity of code that you produce.

I've come across XSLT code that always uses xsl:element rather than LREs and it's far less readable.